# Scaffold with floating Topbar (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

I need a `topbar` in `Scaffold` composable which floats over the main content (body). Currently  the `Scaffold` puts the `topbar` on the main content. This reduces the size of the main content which should fill the entire screen.

[image: Jetpack compose Scaffold and Topbar: Current and expected behaviors]

Comment: ok, but in this way the topAppBar will cover the main content.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I am planning to add padding above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can add TopAppBar composable in your content section of Scaffold

```
Scaffold {
      Box {
           BodyContent()
           TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
           }
      }
}
```